# What happens if you ambassador a hovel?

Tags: dominion, dominion-seaside, dominion-dark-ages

In Dominion, what happens when you [Ambassador](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Ambassador) (Seaside) a [Hovel](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Hovel) (Dark Ages)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing happens at all.

There's a (likely unofficial) rules clarification on [Ambassador](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Ambassador)'s Dominion Strategy wiki:

> If you reveal a card which is not in the Supply, such as Spoils, Madman, Mercenary, or Shelters, Ambassador does nothing.

The same article also quotes an official FAQ clarification:

> If the pile for the chosen card runs out, some players may not get one; cards are given out in turn order starting with the next player.

Since Hovels *are not present in the Supply*, you cannot return your hovels there. Further, nobody can gain them: since they aren't available in the Supply, they are effectively perpetually out of stock.